# Python not catching control-C trap

Tags: python, python-3.x, interrupt, interrupt-handling

Python console is not detecting trap, I have no idea why. I have looked at all the examples using the signal trap and it should work.

```
import signal
import sys

def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    global run
    run = False
    print('Stopping')
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    print("starting main")
    #my_thread = threading.Thread(target=simulate())
    #my_thread.start()
    
    while(1):
        None
```

Comment: Works for me. Are you on a unix-like or windows?

Comment: Are you running this from a command line, or inside one of the warm and cozy Python IDEs?

Comment: I am running from the command line, though in a conda env.

Comment: Does this exact version of your code cause a problem, or only the real one that seems to make use of threads?

Comment: Both, but it appears to work in the Spyder env.